# Team Explorer Everywhere Check In Policy

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

Does the TFS 2015 server maintain two separate lists of check in policies which are enforced for a team project -- one for the Visual Studio client and another for the Team Explorer Everywhere client? This appears to be the behavior I am seeing.

If I look at the Check In policy settings for a Team Project via Visual Studio I see a number of Check In policies configured. If I look at the Check In Policy settings for the same Team Project via Team Explorer Everywhere I do not see any check in policies. Likewise, if I add a check in policy via Team Explorer Everywhere for a specific Team Project it does not show up if I query the check in policies via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behavior.

> Check-in policies that you define by using Team Explorer Everywhere
>   **only apply when you check in by using the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse or the Cross-platform Command-Line Client for Team
>   Foundation Server**.
>
> If you use another client, such as Team Web Access or **Team Explorer
>   in Visual Studio, these policies do not apply.** Similarly, policies
>   that you define by using Team Web Access or Team Explorer in Visual
>   Studio are not applied when you check in by using the Team Foundation
>   Server plug-in for Eclipse or the Cross-platform Command-Line Client
>   for Team Foundation Server.

More details please refer this link: **[Configuring Check-in Policies (Team Explorer Everywhere)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890(v=vs.100).aspx)**

You could also find corresponding info from check in policy with visual studio:

> Visual Studio 2017 : Check-in policies in Visual Studio 2017 must be
>   set through Team Explorer, tf.exe, or through registry keys declared
>   in the pkgdef of a Visual Studio extension. **Policies only apply a
>   single installation of Visual Studio 2017 on your computer.** If you
>   have mulitple installations of Visual Studio 2017, you'll need to set
>   the check-in policy on each installation.
>
> *[Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies)*